# Defining Set in z3

Tags: z3

To create a Sets of 3 elements (1,2,3) in Z3, I am using the follows code:

```
(define-sort Set () ( Array Int Bool ) )
(declare-const s Set ) 
( assert  ( and ( = ( select s 1 ) true )  ( = ( select s 2 ) true ) 
           ( = ( select s 3 ) true )  ) )
```

The Model I am getting is as follows :

```
(model 
  (define-fun s () (Array Int Bool)
    (_ as-array k!0))
  (define-fun k!0 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
    (ite (= x!1 2) true
    (ite (= x!1 3) true
    (ite (= x!1 1) true
      true))))
)
```

But instead how can I get a model of the form :

```
(model    (define-fun s () (Array Int Bool)
    (_ as-array k!0))   (define-fun k!0 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
    (ite (= x!1 2) true
    (ite (= x!1 3) true
    (ite (= x!1 1) true
      false)))) )
```

So that elements other than the set members are not included in the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by starting from the empty set, i.e. the array that is defined to be `false` everywhere.

Here is [an example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/slri):

```
(declare-const s1 (Array Int Bool))

(assert (= s1
  (store
    (store
      (store 
        ((as const (Array Int Bool)) false)
        1 true)
      2 true)
    3 true)
))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works perfectly. But it creates a lot of temporary functions. Can these unused temporary functions be removed from the model ?

Comment: You can use explicit select calls to get individual elements: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/88WD

As far as I know there's no other way to display just `s1` using this technique, assuming you want to stick to SMT-Lib. You can, however, use programmatic interfaces to query the models in detail, depending on the API-set you choose to use.